# Dynamically create Imageviews

Tags: android

I have to create Dynamically list of **Imageview** in a row, There is an other Imageview (dot Drawable) under Each Imageview.
see below pic which is my desired view.

[image]

Here is my source.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ImageView catImg = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        catImg.setImageResource(bottDrawableArr[i]);
        catImg.setId(View.generateViewId());
        int dp = (int) utiles.convertDpToPixel(27, getApplicationContext());
        params1.height = dp;
        params1.width = dp;
        ImageView dotImg = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        dotImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.dot);
        dotImg.setId(View.generateViewId());

        params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, dotImg.getId());
        dockBg.addView(catImg, params1);
        dockBg.addView(dotImg, params2);
    }
```

But I am Unable to get my desire view,

while my views show like this

[image]

I tried to put dot under each image but unable to achieve that.

Comment: Do you have to create them dynamically through code? or could you use a RecyclerView and ViewHolders and pass a list of Drawable resources into the adapter?

Comment: I want to create through the code, its simple Array no use of Adapter.

Comment: I am not restrict to use my code, if any other way like RecyclerView and viewHolder it will be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is working with some `LinearLayout`, something like this:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

    LinearLayout layoutChild = new LinearLayout(this);
    layoutChild.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ImageView catImg = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    catImg.setImageResource(bottDrawableArr[i]);
    catImg.setId(View.generateViewId());
    int dp = (int) utiles.convertDpToPixel(27, getApplicationContext());
    params1.height = dp;
    params1.width = dp;
    ImageView dotImg = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    dotImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.dot);
    dotImg.setId(View.generateViewId());

    params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, dotImg.getId());
    layoutChild.addView(catImg, params1);
    layoutChild.addView(dotImg, params2);
    layout.addView(layoutChild);
}

dockBg.addView(layout);
```

**Note:** it's better to delete the unnecessary properties like setting some rules...

Answer (score 0):

```
params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, dotImg.getId());
```

This line of code looks like you are trying to add a rule to put the `dotImg` below the `dotImg`. Replacing that with `catImg.getId()` should fix your issue.

It might be a good idea to consider a RecyclerView though, Or if it is a static array (always the same items) then you could make a new layout file and just inflate it when you need it.

Comment: basically it is not static array it may change

Comment: you are also right. RecyclerView is second best option